# Creating Vector Buffers in QGIS 3

Tags: vector, geometry, buffer, qgis-3, measurements

I am mapping the accessibility of job opportunities in Detroit for those who rely on public transportation.  To do this, I need to create a circular buffer surrounding each bus stop with a radius extending out a mile in every direction. One mile represents the average time it takes a person to walk 20 minutes, a value chosen based on empirical research that an average person walks 4.5 feet a second (or 3 miles per hour).

In ArcGIS 3.0, I only see a "Variable Distance Buffer" tool under Vector--> Geoprocessing Tools. [image] (See pic below).  But these fields are not intuitive to me, even after clicking the help button.  Where and how do I specify 1 mile for the radius measurement to extend out from the point in all directions?  P.S. I should add I do not yet know python, so looking for alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are currently using QGIS 3.0.0 or 3.0.1.

Latest QGIS 3.0.2 does not have `Variable distance buffer` anymore.

What you can find in the `Vector | Geoprocessing Tools` menu would simply be a **Buffer**.

[image]

It is the same in the Processing Toolbox... First. `Fixed distance buffer` disappeared, and now `Variable distance buffer`. There is only **Buffer** tool left.

[image]

Now with this **Buffer** tool, you will easily find `Distance` option. In case you need to apply a `variable distance`, click on the `Data defined override` icon and select the field you want to assign to.

Comment: I looked at this buffer tool, as well, and I'm unclear what units the "distance" field is measured in.  I want to measure 1 mile

Comment: @Ashley The unit is the map unit, which is based on your projection.

Comment: @Ashley You might want to try 5280 (ft) for 1 (mile) and see how it goes.